# Java Error Database sql Commands Unexpected Token

Tags: java, sql, ucanaccess

when I am trying to insert some data into the database it gives me this error

[![ unexpected token][1]][1]

my insert query is correct
its

This is my insertion query any wrong bracket places in the string are not wrong because i copied it from the console and because of the Arabic language in the print the bracket places are not correct

Comment: timestamp of what ?

Comment: can you show jdbc code? Also try removing extra square brackets from columns part, starting [ and ending ]. The first one and last one only.

Comment: Some of string in your query do not have single quotes(مصری for example). Also it is better to use N'مصری' instead of 'مصری' when working with Arabic letters.

Comment: Thanks @farshad

Comment: You are most welcome @HummelGoodspeedHummelgoodspe . Please Use vote up if a comment or answer is useful.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, post the exception stacktrace as text. Also post the code used to execute.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to add values same type of added column 
  `nvarchar` has to be surround with single quote  => 'قسم العجوزة'
  `null` without single quote => null
  numbers `int,bigint,bit` no need for single quote  => 389.0
- inserted values has to match columns